# Check if a value is in a list of routes, if yes new list append 1, else 0

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an automatic method check if a value `i` exists in a `list[list]` of routes. If so, the new `bir` list (check the presence of the location by each route) `append(1)` if location exists on the route, or otherwise `append(0)`.

Example:

```
routes=[[(0, 1), (1, 3), (3,0)], [(0,2), (2,0)]] #2 routes
```

My attempt:

```
bir=[]
for i in range(1,N): # N=4 (not counting the 0 - depot).
    if i in range(len(routes)):
        bir[i].append(1)
    else:
        bir[i].append(0)
```

I also tried Python list comprehension, but without success.

What I'd like to get was something like this:

```
bir=[[1,0],[0,1],[1,0]]
```

That is, it is clear that, for example, location `i=1` is present on route 1 and not on route 2, while location `i=2` is only present on route 2. Location `i=3`, in turn, is also only present on route 1 and not on route 2.

Any suggestions for my problem?

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but which part? the problem itself?
I don't know if it's my fault, sorry. but my question is through an automatic cycle, to check if the locations of my range `N` (not counting the 0) are present in my list of 2 `routes` (list of arcs). If yes, i.e. i=1 present in route 1, `bir` append(1), otherwise, append(0). The result I wanted to get was `bir=[[1,0],[0,1],[1,0]]`. That is, location i=1 is present on route 1 and not on route 2 (`[1,0]`), and so on. Thanks

Comment: `i in range(len(routes))` is the same as `i < len(routes)`. Neither of them is checking whether a value is in `routes`, it's just checking the length.

Comment: You said what you want to do but not what the problem is with what you have shown.

Comment: @mkrieger1 When I run OP's code 'as-is' I get an `IndexError` caused by `bir[i].append()` - `bir` is an empty list, so `bir[i]` doesn't exist. FWIW, just using `bir.append()` works, but doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Ignoring everything else how are you trying to convert routes to bir?  For the first part what logic gets you from (0, 1), (1, 3), (3,0) to (1,0), (0,1), (1,0) ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a Vehicle Routing Problem. Look at the Gurobi tsp.py example for some illustrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This genuinely hurt my head to get around, thanks for the question was fun to work out!

```
routes = [[(0, 1), (1, 3), (3, 0)], [(0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]]

bir = []
# check values 1, 2, 3
for i in range(1, 4):
    # check every route
    for x in range(len(routes)):
        # check if bir contains an empty list for the value we are currently checking
        try:
            bir[i-1]
        # if there is no empty list, create one
        except IndexError:
            bir.append([])
        # check if the route exists
        try:
            # if our value exists in the route then append 1
            if i in routes[x][i - 1]:
                bir[i-1].append(1)
            # if the value does not exists append 0
            else:
                bir[i-1].append(0)
        # if the route does not exist append 0
        except IndexError:
            bir[i - 1].append(0)

print(bir)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bir = []
N = 4

for i in range(1, N):
    bir.append([])  # insert a new sub-list for results
    for route in routes:
        if any(i in point for point in route):
            # 'i-1' because of 0-indexing
            # indexing is needed to insert into sub-lists
            # instead of appending directly to 'bir'
            bir[i-1].append(1)
        else:
            bir[i-1].append(0)
```

Edit to say that this can be cleaned up a bit if you're okay with `bir` containing True/False instead of 1/0:

```
for i in range(1, N):
    bir.append([])  # create a new sub-list for results
    for route in routes:
        bir[i-1].append(any(i in point for point in route))

# results in -> bir = [[True, False], [False, True], [True, False]]
```